# disable cropping featured image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, crop

I am using featured image as a post image but on uploading a image it crops while setting it as featured image, i dnt find any solution for it, Can any one help?

**Wordpress Admin panel screenshot:**-

[image]

This image is actually **1024x702** but it cuts to **940x198**, i cant find any soltuion for this how to disabling the cropping...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how to disable cropping but you could try to use [add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) function to register a bigger image size.

Something like this: (add this in functions.php)

```
add_image_size( 'featuredImageCropped', 1024, 768, true );
```

And then locate the_post_thumbnail in the template and modify it like this:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'featuredImageCropped' );
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, ya i tried your soltions but it is not showing the approraite result, ofcourse image is cropping at adminpanel but on result in the front page of the website...http://i.imgur.com/YaYJOqu.jpg?1

Comment: Have you edited the correct template? Try comment out the_post_thumbnail( 'featuredImageCropped' ); to see if the thumbnail will disappear.

Comment: its working now, http://i.imgur.com/PJYPsQK.jpg?1, i dnt know that but it is, thanks for ur time...

Answer (score 0):

Inside your theme there is file called functions.php - inside functions.php you will find a line of code similar to this:

```
add_image_size('featured', 940, 198, true);
```

These parameters are the name, width, height, and crop.

When crop is set to "true" your image will be resized so that it fills the width-height dimensions completely. The shortest side of the image will be equal to the maximum allowed value, and the longest side of the image will be cropped.

When crop is set to "false" your image will be resized so that it fits *inside* the width-height dimensions. The longest side of the image will be equal to the maximum allowed value, and the shorter side of the image will be smaller.

I would recommend playing with these settings to achieve the exact effect that you're after. Most likely what you want is *not* to disable cropping, but rather to simply increase the maximum allowed height of your featured image.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i dont find anything in functions.php as `add_image_size()`, i am using twentyten theme...

Comment: On line 116 and 117 you will find

`define( 'HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH', apply_filters( 'twentyten_header_image_width', 940 ) );`
`define( 'HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT', apply_filters( 'twentyten_header_image_height', 198 ) );`

Try playing with these :)

Comment: can i set these width and height to auto, can it be possible...