# How to disable cropping for the featured image on the homepage

Tags: css, crop, background-size

I am building a website using wordpress and the theme is "Infinite Photography".
 
My problem is: on the homepage you see the featured images of all posts: [www.konradfoerster.de/wordpress](http://www.konradfoerster.de/wordpress) 
When I change the size of the browser window, the images will be cropped from the middle. I don't want that.
However when you click on an image and open a single post and then change the size of the screen, the image scales but it does not crop. I want this behaviour for the homepage too! 
I need the behavior like here: https://demo.kaliumtheme.com/photography/. Here when you make the browser window smaller, the images will be just scaled, not cropped.
 
How can I do this? I googled a lot, but could not find anything. For example I tried this one, but it did not work. [disable cropping featured image in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810671/disable-cropping-featured-image-in-wordpress)

Would appreciate any hints.

Edit: here is the screenshot of the document inspector. I think the styles, that apply for each image are in the class .acme-col-3.
[screenshot document inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af4IQ.png)

Comment: You're required to show code or markup here, in your question. External links aren't considered adequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.masonry-item.post-item {
    ...
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size